# Not able to set font weight to more than 600 for Raleways from Google fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've imported the stylesheet for the Raleway font from Google fonts:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now I need to use its extra bold option with:

```
h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 52px;
}
```

However, it doesn't work. Same goes for 700 and 900:

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/OWQmWj

[image]

What might be the reason?

Comment: how do you have it used in your html? cause it looks like it works at the link

Comment: @Keith, this is what I see it like (uploaded a pic). Is it different at your screen?

Comment: Have you installed Raleway on your local machine?

Comment: Yeah it works on my machine. Try James's way, not sure what else it could be

Comment: Correct, it got on my machine somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be working on your Codepen example.

If you have Raleway installed locally that could be causing the issue - check your machine and delete / disable if you have

Comment: It's installed on my machine, you are right. Thanks!